# How to download information from a website

Tags: php, vba

I'm trying to automatically download information from a website based on a few parameters. Essentially I want to specify the parameters of a search and have the function automatically navigate to the appropriate website and download the file. Note that all of the files are excel file, usually .csv.

Here's the website:http://comtrade.un.org/db/

NOTE: This websites address will be updated depending on the search, so, for instance, if you search trade from the united states to iran (The rest of the parameters are unspecified), the result is:

http://comtrade.un.org/db/dqBasicQueryResults.aspx?px=HS&cc=TOTAL&r=364&p=842&rg=1&y=2010,2009,2008,2007,2006&so=8

More on this here:

http://unstats.un.org/unsd/tradekb/Knowledgebase/Data-Extraction-Using-Comtrade-Web-Service
Look under web service methods and parameters

Two Question:

1) How can I do this?

2) What is the best language to do this in?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with VBA?!

Comment: The files are all excel files, I was just assuming there is a method to retrieve files using that programming language.

Answer (score 2):

There is just no "best language". You can do this by any language with HTTP access availability, this could be either PHP, Java, RoR, Perl, Python...

On [the link you posted](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/tradekb/Knowledgebase/Data-Extraction-Using-Comtrade-Web-Service), you can read they are offering REST service for accessing the data in XML.

In PHP, you would first have to download the file using appropriate URL:

```
$xml = file_get_contents("http://comtrade.un.org/ws/...");
```

Than use PHP's XML functions to parse the file.

I'm not sure about their license of data usage - you might not be legally permitted to automatically download data from here.

**UPDATE**
You cannot directly download the files found in the search results (through PHP e.g.) - so you HAVE to use the REST access, but some parts of it are obviously accessible only if UN allow you to do so. If you would try to download directly the "excel" (in fact CSV) files, you will end up with error like this: http://comtrade.un.org/db/dqBasicQueryResultsd.aspx?action=csv&px=HS&cc=TOTAL&r=364&p=842&rg=1&y=2010,2009,2008,2007,2006&so=8. You can spoof the `HTTP_REFERER` value, but **you will break the terms of the service.**

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, use `file_get_contents("http://............");`

Plug in whatever URL and GET parameters you want, and you instantly have the data, in this case the CSV, which you can then process.